# Database 'default' not found sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, sparklyr

I am receiving this intermittent error '*org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.NoSuchDatabaseException: Database 'default' not found;*'
I am running scripts in R-studio and receiving this error randomly. If I go on Spark UI then it shows no failure. 
If I run the code again the code will execute successfully. Basically, same code will give this error sometimes or sometimes it gets executed successfully. 
I am wondering why sometimes the Default database is not found and why sometimes it is found.
Most of the times this error occur at the time of compute. Like on below code:

```
baseData <- tbl(sc,"baseData")
baseData %>% 
  filter(spinNo==1) %>%
  transmute(
    sessionIdNew,
    initial = initial,
    initial2 = MM, 
    initiabet = tbet,
    initial_bet_to_bank_ratio = totalbet/bank,
    initial_balance = bank + moneyMeter,
    initial_cumCoinIn = cumCoinInNew,
    sessionFirstCoinIn = firstCoinIn
  ) %>% compute("initial_variables")
```

below is the full error:

```
Error: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.NoSuchDatabaseException: Database 'default' not found;
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$catalog$SessionCatalog$$requireDbExists(SessionCatalog.scala:178)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.listTables(SessionCatalog.scala:764)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ShowTablesCommand$$anonfun$15.apply(tables.scala:791)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ShowTablesCommand$$anonfun$15.apply(tables.scala:791)
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ShowTablesCommand.run(tables.scala:791)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:79)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply(Dataset.scala:194)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply(Dataset.scala:194)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3370)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3369)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:194)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:79)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:642)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sparklyr.Invoke.invoke(invoke.scala:147)
at sparklyr.StreamHandler.handleMethodCall(stream.scala:136)
at sparklyr.StreamHandler.read(stream.scala:61)
at sparklyr.BackendHandler$$anonfun$channelRead0$1.apply$mcV$sp(handler.scala:58)
at scala.util.control.Breaks.breakable(Breaks.scala:38)
at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:38)
at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:14)
at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:328)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:302)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1422)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:931)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:700)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:635)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:552)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:514)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1044)
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Note:- I am using Google cloud platform. Debian 9, Hadoop 2.9, Spark 2.3, RSTUDIO_SERVER_VERSION=1.2.5019
sparlyr1.2.0

Comment: It might help if you include the code that you think is causing this error.

Comment: Please See the edited question.